# Incorrect transaction fee estimation when payout

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain, blockchain, rewards, transaction-fees

I have been working on payout in my `L0` `relay chain`  blockchain .While making payout I have observed the transaction fee that is deducted from my account and the actual fee that is been deducted are different, what I see from events the extra deducted fee is deposited back to my account. I want to know why extra fee get deducted from my account and then deposited back again.

eg.  lets suppose i have made  payout transaction from  `A`  account.

1. 0.2 units fee gets deducted
2. 0.18units   gets credited  to my account.
3. 0.02units fee gets deducted this way.

I am sharing the screenshot for the same.

[image: image1]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you did was calling `Staking::payout_stakers`. This call first deduces the worst-case fee and then refunds all amount that was not used.
This is a standard pattern in Substrate when only the worst-case effort is known in advance.
The refund happens [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ffe5db0f7662f80dcf4805d093c6736880c0fb4d/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L278) where a `DispatchResultWithPostInfo` is returned that corrects the consumed weight downwards. Note that it is only possible to reduce it downwards - not upwards, since the provided pre-dispatch weight must always be the worst-case.